# can we download CQ package share packages from (Adobe Experience Manager package share)

Tags: package, aem

Can you please let me know. I have the adobe id access and can we download the packages from Adobe Experience Manager package share using package share option?

please let me know those packages are free or we have to pay any cost.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I have an adobe id and I can confirm that all of the packages on the package share are available free of charge.